# Migrate existing standalone store from Magento 2.0 to Magento 2.3 Multiple websites or stores

Tags: magento2.3, migration

### - The migration includes the theme, custom modules, and DB

> - What is the migration process?
> - Is there any plug-in or extension module readily available which can help with migration activity?

Comment: you means magento 1 to 2 data migration right ??

Comment: Standalone website magento 2.0 to magento 2.3 multi-store website.